# Why was move 26 in Carlsen-Anand 2014 WC Game 6 a blunder by both players?

Tags: blunder, carlsen-anand-2014

In the Anand vs Carlsen Match 6, why was move 26 a blunder for both players?

```
[White "Carlsen"]
[Black "Anand"]
[FEN "6rr/1k3p2/1pb1p1np/p1p1P2R/2P3R1/2P1B3/P1B2PP1/2K5 w - - 0 1"]

1.Kd2? a4?
```

Comment: http://www.thechesswebsite.com/world-chess-championship-game-6-magnus-carlsen-vs-vishy-anand/ <- Excellent in-depth coverage and explanation

Answer (score 15):

Carlsen's `26.Kd2` is a a blunder because it exposes the White King to a tactic that wins two pawns and gives Black terrific pressure. The tactic is effectively a guarantee of victory for Black:

```
[FEN "6rr/1k3p2/1pb1p1np/p1p1P2R/2P3R1/2P1B3/P1BK1PP1/8 b - - 0 1"]

1...Nxe5! 2.Rxg8 (2.Rxe5? Rxg4) Nxc4+! {The Knight gets out of danger, with check and an extra pawn--you couldn't ask for anything better!} 3.Kd3 (3.Ke2 Rxg8) Nb2+ 4.Ke2 Rxg8 {Black is now two full pawns ahead, with lots of pressure on the weak g2 pawn and vastly better pawns for the endgame. }
```

The point is that `2...Nxc4+` wins Black a second free pawn, by virtue of the check against the White King. Without the ability to get the Knight out of danger with check, `...Nxe5` is not possible (because White could then simply trade Rooks and then recapture the Knight with a winning position).

---

Anand's mistake on *his* twenty-sixth move was that he missed this tactic, playing `26...a4` very quickly and allowing Carlsen to correct his mistake by moving his King away from `d2`.

Comment: It was an unexpected blunder by Carlsen and thus perhaps an explanation to the blunder by Anand. My guess is that Anand did not calculate 26...Nxe5, since I find it hard to imagine that Anand would miss Nc4-b2+ in that variation. While Carlsen played Kc1-d2 thinking that it was equivalent to Kc1-d1 and ignoring the dynamic aspects of the position.

Answer (score 6):

Carlsen's move(26.Kd2) was a blunder because of Anand's practically winning move(26...Nxe5!) which had a discovered attack on the rook on G4(and potential to take on C4). The double blunder occurred when Anand missed this move and played A4 which is a clear blunder when he had another great move available to him.

Comment: So was Carlsen's blunder that he put his King on a square which could be put under attack from c4 and in the process lose 2 pawns?

Comment: @user4247 that is correct.